# Changing width of barplot bars with bargraph.CI()

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

Any ideas on how to change the width of barplot bars with the function `bargraph.CI()` from the `sciplot` pacakge? I have a very simple barplot with 2 bars, and can't figure out how to slim them down. I've tried the argument, width, from the `barplot()` function, but without any success. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the space= argument. As the bar widths specified through width= are all relative, if you just specify one value they will never change size:

E.g.: both of the following give the same result:

```
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth, width=1)
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth, width=1000)
```

[image]

Adjusting `space=` however, pushes the bars apart and indirectly affects their width:

```
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth, space=1)
```

[image]

```
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth, space=5)
```

[image]

To ultimately reduce the size of plots though, you might also look at pushing in the margins or reducing the size of the plotting device. See this previous question:

[reducing the space between plotted points in plot( x, y) type=n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732747/reducing-the-space-between-plotted-points-in-plot-x-y-type-n/18733726#18733726)

Then try something like:

```
par(mar=c(5.1,8,2.1,8))
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth, space=c(1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
barplot(1:3, width=1:3)
```

Works --> maybe give us your code to see what's wrong?